# Пате - это что?

Tags: тире

Можете, пожалуйста, сказать, нужно ли в данном случае (когда есть 'что', а также это вопрос) писать тире и нужно ли само это слово, которое как слово, а не как часть речи с своим смыслом ('паштет' в данном случае), используется, ставить в кавычки?

- Ларчок, а ты любишь пате кушкать?

1. А пате это что?
2. А 'пате' это что?
3. А 'пате' - это что?
4. А пате - это что?

(Какой вариант правильный?)

Answer (score 3):

Правильный 4.
Тире заменяет глагол "есть" в краткой форме предложения. Полная форма: Термин/слово **есть** ... (приводится определение термина). *Зелёный **есть** цвет видимого электромагнитного излучения (света) с длинами волн, лежащими в диапазоне приблизительно 496—555 нм.*
Кавычки должны быть, если они есть при употреблении определяемого слова. Если слово пишется без кавычек, то их и не должно быть.

Comment: Нельзя сказать, что тире заменяет "есть", так как "есть" перед "это" не подходит. Тире в связи с интонацией, "это" разграничивает части. Оно даже в вашем примере требуется по интонации: *Зелёный — это есть цвет видимого электромагнитного излучения.*

Comment: Вы правы, мой пример не совсем понятный. Слово "это" лишнее в полной форме, но может добавляться в краткую. Исправил.

Comment: *Кавычки должны быть, если они есть при употреблении определяемого слова* — спрашивается про кавычки при определяемом слове.

Comment: Пример употребления:  *Ларчок, а ты любишь пате кушкать?* Слово "пате" без кавычек.  Значит и правильный вопрос без кавычек.

Comment: Ага, теперь ясно, а то очень закручено.

Comment: В логике есть целый раздел  про то, как надо определять понятия. Раньше форма: *Термин есть то-то* - была жесткой. А теперь допускается краткая форма с заменой "есть"  на тире с возможным добавлением слова "это". Так писали в учебнике (для средней школы) "Логика"  в 1954 году.

Comment: Когда было жёстким? Справочник Розенталя выпущен в этом десятилетии. Наверно, в предыдущих столетиях или в каких-то особых случаях. Использование "есть" носит философский характер.

Comment: Да, я тоже так думаю, скорее всего  есть это пережиток аристотелевой логики.